# Solving this ODE on MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the following ODE -

$\frac{dn}{dt} = \frac{1-n}{A} - \frac{u(t)}{B}n , -30\leq t\leq30, n(-30)=1$

where $A,B$ are constants and $n = n(t)$.

I can solve this ODE analytically and get an expression for $n(t)$, but I'd like to do it numerically.

Assuming $u(t), n(t)$ and $t$ are vectors of the same length (with $t$ being a linearly spaced vector between -30 and 30), is there any way to find the solution of this ODE numerically?

I tried using ODE45, but it appears it cannot be used for some arbitrary vector $u$ and instead requires an expression for $u(t)$ in terms of $t$ which may not always be possible in my problem.

I do however know that $u(t)$ goes to zero well before the boundaries. Therefore, the choice of boundary conditions may not be an issue.

Comment: $u,n$ and $t$ are all vectors. I have edited the question to reflect that. And $u(t) n$ indeed represents component-wise multiplication. The analytical solution of the ODE does exist, but it is messy and somewhat tedious to calculate and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: The problem I am facing is when I do not know the analytical form of $u(t)$. For instance, it could be some arbitrary signal. That is when ODE45 fails. It seems to require an expression to evaluate $u(t)$ at any value of $t$ while I cannot do that because I only know $u$ at those specific values of $t$. Basically, $u(t)$ is some arbitrarily sampled signal.

Comment: Ahh okay, ODE45 does require a specific $u(t)$ and might require it to be defined on all of $[t_i, t_f]$ since it uses some advanced variant of a 4th order Runge-Kutta method (I don't know the details). You could write your own [forward Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) method that can use just the known $u(t)$ values.

Comment: Fair enough. I was trying to avoid writing my own function for this. It is a little surprising that MATLAB does not come with an inbuilt Euler or RK4 routine that I can use. Thanks anyway!